# React - Phone input produces a huge flag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface

This is my jsx for the form

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { createUser } from "../HTTPRequests";
import PhoneInput from "react-phone-number-input";

class UserRegForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      secondPassword: "",
      username: "",
      phone: "",
      current: 0
    };
    this.handleEmail = this.handleEmail.bind(this);
    this.handlePassword = this.handlePassword.bind(this);
    this.handleSecondPassword = this.handleSecondPassword.bind(this);
    this.handleUsername = this.handleUsername.bind(this);
    this.renderSecondPassword = this.renderSecondPassword.bind(this);
    this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this);
    this.handlePhone = this.handlePhone.bind(this);
  }

  handleEmail(event) {
    this.setState({ email: event.target.value });
  }

  handlePassword(event) {
    this.setState({ password: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSecondPassword(event) {
    this.setState({ secondPassword: event.target.value });
  }

  handleUsername(event) {
    this.setState({ username: event.target.value });
  }

  handlePhone(phone) {
    this.setState({ phone: phone.value });
  }

  renderSecondPassword() {
    var classN;

    if (
      this.state.secondPassword.length === 0 ||
      this.state.secondPassword === this.state.password
    ) {
      classN = "form-control";
    } else {
      classN = "form-control is-invalid";
    }

    return (
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="InputPassword2">Introduza novamente a Password</label>
        <input
          onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
          onChange={this.handleSecondPassword}
          type="password"
          className={classN}
          id="InputPassword2"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleKeyDown(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      this.handleSubmit();
    }
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    createUser(this.state.email, this.state.password, this.state.username).then(
      function(r) {
        console.log(r);
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="position-relative m-4">
        <form>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="exampleInputUsername">Nome Completo</label>
            <input
              onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
              onChange={this.handleUsername}
              type="username"
              className="form-control"
              id="exampleInputUsername"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">E-mail</label>
            <input
              onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
              onChange={this.handleEmail}
              type="email"
              className="form-control"
              id="exampleInputEmail1"
              aria-describedby="emailHelp"
            />
            <small id="emailHelp" className="form-text text-muted">
              Nunca partilharemos o seu e-mail com ninguém.
            </small>
          </div>
          <PhoneInput
            placeholder="Enter phone number"
            value={this.state.phone}
            onChange={phone => this.handlePhone({ phone })}
          />
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="InputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input
              onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
              onChange={this.handlePassword}
              type="password"
              className="form-control"
              id="InputPassword1"
            />
          </div>
          {this.renderSecondPassword()}
          <button
            type="button"
            className="btn btn-primary"
            onClick={this.handleSubmit}
          >
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UserRegForm;
```

And this is the result...

[image: result]

as you can see the flag just expands to the whole screen.
I have programming experience (C and java), but just started learning HTML and React... So i'm still a bit lost. do I have to wrap the phone number component in something so it behaves? According to documentation the flag should be to the left of the input and not below
Any help is very appreciated

Comment: Did you check the css? Probable, your css class has interfere with the class of the flag.

Comment: I forgot to close this, I solved it already. Yes, it was a CSS problem

Comment: Glad to know that. Instead of using global class. Actually u can try styled-components. It is easy and don't mess up globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone who just encountered the same issue as OP after an update, the fix was very simple:

> import 'react-phone-number-input/style.css'

According to last version of the docs : https://github.com/catamphetamine/react-phone-number-input

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the css. It's in the documentation.
add this line in top of file.

```
import 'react-phone-number-input/style.css'
```